# managing single dashboard menu in multiple activities

Tags: android, android-layout, dashboard, android-menu

in my app I've launcher activity displaying summaries of different stuff. There's one **SlidingDrawer** set up in each activity having a dashboard with 9 menus as content. When user clicks on drawer's handle, content scrolls up to display that dashboard. These menu launch 9 activities from dashboard and there are no of activities that will be having same SlidingDrawer with dashboard.

Now the thing which is disturbing me is, I'm forced to put same code blocks in each activity that controls behaviour of dashboard. Dashboard itself is inflated from single layout. So design is not issue. But I've to attach event handlers to each button and start new activities from there.  Problem is whenever I make changes I need to replicate those changes in all activities.

How can I avoid such redundant code and use a single class or something that let me define launching of those 9 activities?

Sorry for title and description. It's really hard for me to put it in words. If you find title or description not suitable then tell me or edit where appropriate.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might be a perfect situation for an [Android Fragment](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html)

Have two fragments for each activity, one for the sliding drawer and one for everything else.

Android fragments seem complex at first, but trust me, learning them will make your life easier.

Comment: thanks jameo. I'll try to use fragments. I still have doubt because I'm using ABS already and have to see if I can extend fragment.

Comment: ABS? Im not familiar with that

Comment: it's Actionbar sherlock library by Jake Wharton. You can find out more here http://actionbarsherlock.com/  it's damn easy to create action bars and view pagers, fragments with abs for older apis.

Comment: I've never seen that before, but it looks cool.  Did that work for you?

Comment: yeah. I'm actually working with it right now. :D It's huge pain in making app compatible with older version having `Actionbar`. But with ABS it's so simple. My app works smoothly on 2.1 with Actionbars. :))

Comment: Wow thats awesome! Good luck!!